# Execute JQuery Validate on Given Condition

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to call JQuery Validate Function if it meets certain criteria?
e.g.
I've got form with few radio buttons. One of the radio button shows extra few text fields if selected yes.

i want to validate (make mandatory) if yes is selected.

If anyone could tell me how one can achieve will be much appreciated.

Comment: of course you can do this using `jQuery selected` text value

Comment: Are you able to show me how please? If I decorate Jquery validate method in if statement it never seem to execute.

Comment: I tried this below and doesn't seem to work. rules: {

                    StartTime:
                    {
                        required: $('input:radio[name=radioBtnname]:checked').val() == "No"
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are jQuery form validation plugins, but if you need something simple then this is all it takes to validate form input:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    if ( $('#btnYes', this).is(':checked') )
        return true;
    else {
        displayError();
        return false; //Stop the form from submitting
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using this one and not working if I want to put some smart (i.e. check to see if user has selected yes on radio button and then only validate else do not validate.)
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jquery/form_validation/